# Redirect showing blank page

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to GET a return url for when a user is redirected back to the login page. Upon relogging in they need to be redirected back to the page they were on. I have tried many different ways of doing it. However it only shows a blank page.

Here is the code from the login page:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($fgmembersite->Login())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL(str_replace("'", "", $_GET['redirecturl']));
   }
}
```

Here is the code from the page that checks the login for the redirect:

```
function RedirectToURL($url)
{

    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Does the URL change in the address bar?  Can you check via Firebug or similar what the response code is (i.e. 200 OK, 302 Moved Temporarily, 303, ...)

Comment: it just gives me a blank page now change in url.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: redirecturl in /home/johnwall/public_html/source/login.php on line 8

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/johnwall/public_html/source/login.php:8) in /home/johnwall/public_html/source/include/fg_membersite.php on line 303

Comment: I added ob_start; and ob_end; I am now getting: Notice: Undefined index: redirecturl in /home/johnwall/public_html/source/login.php on line 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first it would not let me modify the header. Adding ob_start(); and ob_end(); allowed me to modify the header. I then had to throw up a custom if statement, the error was occurring when there was no redirecturl querysting identifier at all. Thanks for all the help guys.

`if (!isset($_GET['redirecturl'])){echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];} else {echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];}`

Comment: Just so you know, the `ob_start`/`ob_end` are not the solution to your problem, your problem is with the Notice you got, which messed with the `header`, and that if statement solves the notice. There could be another problem that would prevent the redirect from working: so you either wrap **all** your page with output buffering `ob_XXX`, or just make sure nothing is `echo`'ed before you call `header`.

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing the $url in `RedirectToURL($url)` instead of throwing a header to check if:

1. it's valid URL
2. it actually gets called

Your problem is one of theese two. Also it could be the case, that something was echoed before you call `header()` function. In that case the `header()` doesn't work as it can only work before any output is sent to browser.

Comment: Then I'd say it's the header after some output was sent issue. Check your php logs for errors or use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','On');` at start of the script to find out if that's the case. If it is, it will say something like *can't modify headers, output already sent*.

Comment: I assume line 9 is `$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL(str_replace("'", "", $_GET['redirecturl']));`. When $_GET['redirecturl'] is empty, it throws the error. You need to check if the variable exist before calling a function, you don't want to redirect user to nowhere